# How can I extract words from a comma-separated string using LINQ?

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a string like:

```
string features="name1,name2,name3,name4,name5,name6,name7";
```

Now I want to extract all names and store the results in a string array using LINQ. Is this possible?

If not then please tell me the easiest method for doing this.

I have done it like this, but want to do it using LINQ.

```
string Allfeat = txtFeatures.Text;
string sep = ",";
string[] feat = Allfeat.Split(sep.ToCharArray());
```

Comment: The way you are doing it is already the best way.

Comment: You don't need LINQ, `Allfeat.Split(',')` would give you the required array.

Comment: [How to: Split Strings (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest:

```
string[] feat  = Allfeat.Split(',');
```

`LINQ` is awesome and very useful for most cases.But you don't have to use `LINQ` all the time.In this case there are several overloaded versions of `Split` method.One of them takes [`params char[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as parameter so you can easily pass `zero` or `more` seperators.Also in your case if you want to simplify it you don't need that `Allfeat` variable, you can use `txtFeatures.Text` directly.

```
string[] feat = txtFeatures.Text.Split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own in Linq, like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> CsvSplit( this IEnumerable<char> text , char delimiter = ',' )
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
  foreach ( char c in text )
  {
    if ( c == delimiter )
    {
      yield return sb.ToString() ;
      sb.Length = 0 ;
    }
    else
    {
      sb.Append(c) ;
    }
  }
  if ( sb.Length > 0 )
  {
    yield return sb.ToString() ;
  }
}
```

Or you could use regular expressions, something along these lines:

```
private static Regex rxWord = new Regex( @"[^,]*") ;
public static IEnumerable<string> CsvSplit( this string text )
{
  for ( Match m = rxWord.Match(text) ; m.Success ; m = m.NextMatch() )
  {
    yield return m.Value ;
  }
}
```

But what's wrong with `string.Split()`? Though, parsing anything but a trivial CSV text isn't as simple as it might seem :D — you might want to look at using Sebastien Lorion's most excellent [Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader):

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader